# Abstracting a large number of similar ASP.NET MVC Actions (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

A new MVC 5 app that I'm working on references a large-ish collection (4 assemblies, about 500 classes each) of data models generated from a 4GL environment.  The basic interaction has the MVC app present and populate a model instance, then (after model validation), hand the model instance off to a provider for processing.

The initial approach I've used is, for each model, create

- a scaffolded razor view bound to the model,
- a partial controller class with a pair of actions (GET/POST) the model

All of the actions are part of the same controller class which has a couple of private methods to implement the GET & POST actions exposed in each of the partials.

So, the structure is like:

```
|
|--\Controllers
       |
       |--MyController.cs
       |--MyController.MDL001.cs
       |--MyController.MDL002.cs
       |-- ...
       |--MyController.MDL500.cs

|--\Views
       |
       |--\My
            |--\MDL001.cshtml
            |--\MDL002.cshtml
            |-- ...
            |--\MDL500.cshtml
```

And the implementation of each partial controller follows the pattern:

```
public partial class MyController
{
    public ActionResult ProcessMDL001(MDL001Model modelInstance)
    {
        return ProcessModel(modelInstance);
    }

    public ActionResult MDL001()
    {
        return ShowModel("MDL001");
    }
}
```

Where methods `ProcessModel(...)` and `ShowModel(...)` are defined in `MyController.cs`

I want to keep MVC's model binding and validation functioning but also am keen on avoiding a few thousand nearly-identical concrete action implementations.    Is there some pattern/approach using routing, generics, dynamics, etc. that can help here?

Comment: What is an `MDL001Model`?  How does it differ from an `MDL002Model`?

Comment: The `MDL001...MDL500Model` classes are just POCOs, each having a different set of properties.  For example, `MDL001{Id, Name}`, `MDL002{Title, CreatedBy, Author}`

Comment: You've got 500 permutations of these things?  How are you managing all of the controller methods... Code Generation?  Is there any commonality at all between the POCO's?

Comment: Yeah, generated from another legacy system.  Actually closer to 2k models when it all shakes out.  They do all share are a couple of common properties (e.g. `.Version`, `.ModelName`).  It would be possible to modify the generator such that they all implement something like IGeneratedModel if that helped.

Comment: Does the behavior change at all between models, or is this primarily a CRUD scenario?

Comment: Primarily (95%+) CRUD-type interaction with the models.  In a few dozen cases I'd end up with something a bit different in the action implementation.  Ideally, an override or custom action filter could be used in these cases.

Comment: You can get it down to one common object by using an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and reflection, but if you already have 2000 tables in a database and Code Generation that works, I'm not sure it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can roughly treat each class the same, you can handle this with generics:

```
public class BaseController<T> : Controller
    where T : class, new
{
    public ActionResult Process(T modelInstance)
    {
        return ProcessModel(modelInstance);
    }

   ...
}
```

But, you would need to use subclasses instead of partial classes. Essentially, you're just going to implement the action once, and then subclass this base controller to specify the type for the controller instance you're working with:

```
public MDL001ModelController : BaseController<MDL001Model>
{
}
```

If no additional type-specific actions are needed, then that code alone is all you subclass would need to be. However, you can always add additional actions that will only apply to this particular controller instance.

If there are pieces of the common actions that you need to customize slightly, such as validation logic or something, you can provide hooks in your actions. Something along the lines of:

```
public class BaseController<T> : Controller
    where T : class, new
{
    public ActionResult ActionWithHook(T model)
    {
        DoSomeWork(model);
        return View();
    }

    // By default this does nothing, but can be overridden to do something
    internal virtual void DoSomeWork(T model)
    {
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public MDL001ModelController : BaseController<MDL001Model>
{
    internal override void DoSomeWork(MDL001Model model)
    {
        // Do something
    } 
}
```